# Using MATLAB interp1 in order to combine two images with different number of columns

Tags: matlab

I have 2 matrices of numbers(images) with different sizes, which represent some measurement of a 2D object. Each row of the matrices represents a measurement widthwise of the object, at some distance from the source of the object. Each column represents a slice along the object.

I want to merge the two matrices into one matrix (image), so that the second matrix (B), which represents a measurement further from the source, will be below the first matrix (A).

The problem is that matrix A has different sampling than B:

A has 2541 columns, which correspond to the sampling vector: x1 = -6.375 : 0.005 : 6.325 (mm), and

B has 5101 columns, which correspond to the sampling vector: x2 = -25.55 : 0.01 : 25.45 (mm).

I thought to solve the problem by merging the sampling vectors and using interp1 in order to have the two matrices with the same number of columns:

```
x_merged=sort([x1 x2]);

interped_A=interp1(x1, A' , x_merged , 'spline','extrap')';

interped_B=interp1(x2, B' , x_merged , 'spline','extrap')';

y_mm=0.23:0.1:(0.23+0.1*(size(A,1)-1));    

figure; imagesc(x1,y_mm,A); colorbar

figure; imagesc(x_merged,y_mm,interped_A); colorbar
```

However, I encountered a problem doing so:

The resulting image of interped_A (for example), does not have the same value at a certain (x,y) point, as the value of A !!

It is demonstrated below:

The first figure is of A, and it has at the indicated point (for example), a value two orders of magnitude lower than the indicated value of the same point at the second figure, which is of interped_A.

What is the problem and how can I fix it  ? ?

(Please help me!!)

[image: The image of matrix A]

[image: The image of matrix interped_A]

Comment: It's funny I didn't think about it immediately: The problem is that imagesc assumes uniformly spaced x and y axes !